# What is the difference between tomcat running inside eclipse and tomcat running on a server?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I have a java web application that runs perfectly inside eclipse under tomcat-9 server
going to http://localhost runs fine

After i exported the war and deployed as ROOT.war inside a linux tomcat install,
if i go to http://myserver:8080 (the port i configured http) i received TOO_MANY redirect 302
a CTRL+MAJ+I on the browser show the redirect to /

after i have exported the war and deployed as ANOTHERLOC.war inside a linux' tomcat and if i go to http://myserver:8080/ANOTHERLOC i received TOO_MANY redirect 302 as well but i can see with the dev console (CTRL+MAJ+I) show the redirect to /ANOTHERLOC/ANOTHERLOC and next line /ANOTHERLOC/ANOTHERLOC/ANOTHERLOC etc ...

This issue looks to me very strange as it doesn't happen when the app runs inside eclipse.

i'm open to any hint, idea ...

Thanks All
i currently feel like a bee hitting the window's glass

Comment: tomcat does not run on server, it itself is a web server.

Comment: 2 kind of tools can help here: the logs of the Tomcat (and of your application), and the development tools of your browsers. Using them you could understand what is the redirection you get, and what part of the application causes it. Common causes are a proxy in front of the tomcat, or a (security) filter in the application.

Comment: i'm not sure if there can be something in front of tomcat as i'm querying directly tomcat http port and i can see in tomcat access logs my GETs query with all the redirects.
the logs generated by my apps inside catalina.out and tomcat.log shows that the apps  starts but after all query doesn't seem to reach it and the log is not fiiling with any messages.

Comment: @ThierryVanDerPutte: can you add the code snippet where your perform the redirect? If you don't perform any explicitly, do you have a `CONFIDENTIAL` security constraint?

Comment: this is my problem, i don't perform any redirect explicitly. So what do you mean by a security constraint CONFIDENTIAL and how do you set it ? (i didn't write this application which is quite old and the writers are no more here and i don't have any documentation ; then it's quite challenging ... )

Comment: thank All you for your help
the word snippet used by @SergeBallesta gave me and idea
i put a snippet.war inside my tomcat install on the server and it works fine
then it is obviously my app that have a problem and redirects.
i have to deep dive inside it

Comment: @ThierryVanDerPutte: you can read about security contraints in [Oracle's documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bncbk/index.html). A [`@TransportGuarantee`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/servlet/annotation/ServletSecurity.TransportGuarantee.html) annotation can have the same effect: it redirects to the HTTPS version of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat is a server which can be run through any interface and basically your startup.bat file is invoked which actually starts your server. Now this server is essentially a process which your computer runs on a certain port generally 8080(default). There is no difference whether you start the server from eclipse & deploy your war/jars there or you manually run the startup.bat & then go to your browser to add wars/jars.

Comment: in eclipse the app is running fine in debug mode.